# what is wrong with mysql statement

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

this is my statement and what I'm trying to do is get the average amount per user per order, running into problems and don't know how to fix it, 
all help is appreciated

```
SELECT usuarios.email, AVG(pedidos_onlines.total), 
CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%colombia%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) <34873 then 'A'
 WHEN p.nombre like '%colombia%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) >= 52309 then 'B'
 ELSE 'C'
end as SegmentColombia,
CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) <41 then 'A'
 WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) >= 62 then 'B'
 ELSE 'C'
end as SegementPeru
CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) <13 then 'A'
 WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) >= 19 then 'B'
 ELSE 'C'
 end as SEGMENT Ecudador
FROM pedidos_onlines
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = pedidos_onlines.usuario_id 
LEFT JOIN ciudades as c on c.id = pedidos_onlines.ciudad_id
LEFT JOIN paises as p on p.id = c.pais_id
WHERE usuarios.email IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY usuarios.email, p.nombre
```

**Error Message:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%ecuador%' and
>   AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) <13 then 'A' ' at line 10

Comment: I dunno, but I'm guessing you do.  Do you get an error message?  If so, put it in the question.  Are the results not what you expect?  If so, put both what you are getting and what you want in the question.

Comment: here is the latest error message i recived

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%ecuador%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) <13 then 'A'
' at line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be far from what you need.

```
SELECT u.email, AVG(po.total), 
CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%colombia%' and AVG(po.total) <34873 then 'A'
 WHEN p.nombre like '%colombia%' and AVG(po.total) >= 52309 then 'B'
 ELSE 'C'
end as SegmentColombia,
CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(po.total) <41 then 'A'
 WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(po.total) >= 62 then 'B'
 ELSE 'C'
end as SegementPeru,
CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(po.total) <13 then 'A'
 WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(po.total) >= 19 then 'B'
 ELSE 'C'
 end as `SEGMENT Ecudador`
FROM pedidos_onlines as po
LEFT JOIN usuarios as u ON u.id = po.usuario_id 
LEFT JOIN ciudades as c on c.id = po.ciudad_id
LEFT JOIN paises as p on p.id = c.pais_id
WHERE u.email IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.email, p.nombre, 
CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%colombia%' and AVG(po.total) <34873 then 'A'
     WHEN p.nombre like '%colombia%' and AVG(po.total) >= 52309 then 'B'
     ELSE 'C'
    end,
    CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(po.total) <41 then 'A'
     WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(po.total) >= 62 then 'B'
     ELSE 'C'
    end,
    CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(po.total) <13 then 'A'
     WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(po.total) >= 19 then 'B'
     ELSE 'C'
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a comma at the end of the second case:

```
CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) <41 then 'A'
 WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) >= 62 then 'B'
 ELSE 'C'
end as SegementPeru
```

needs to be:

```
CASE WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) <41 then 'A'
 WHEN p.nombre like '%peru%' and AVG(pedidos_onlines.total) >= 62 then 'B'
 ELSE 'C'
end as SegementPeru,
```

Edit:

And also, as pointed out with the second error:

```
SEGMENT Ecudador
```

needs to be

```
`SEGMENT Ecudador`
```

Or you could remove the space.

Comment: awesome thanks however now im getting this error message

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Ecudador,
FROM pedidos_onlines
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = pedidos_onlin' at line 13

Comment: There's a space: "SEGMENT Ecudador" so it thinks your field has an alias, and then expect a comma, rather than "field 'space' field". If there needs to be a space, you could put a ` symbol around the two names. Or you could remove the space.

Comment: I hope that helped. If it did, please be sure to mark it as best answer as per the site's tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour .